# Delaying a delete event

Tags: discord.js

I have a ticket system on my discord.js bot, and when you close it, it instantly closes. I was curious if there was a way to delay it from deleting for 1 hour. Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.channel.name.startsWith('ticket')) return message.channel.send('You are not in a ticket channel!');
    let reason = args[0] | 'Ticket Closed!'
    message.channel.delete(args[0])
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "close"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One easy way to do it is with a simple `setTimeout` function. E.g.:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.channel.name.startsWith('ticket')) return message.channel.send('You are not in a ticket channel!');
    let reason = args[0] | 'Ticket Closed!'

    setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.delete(args[0]);
    }, 60 * 60 * 1000); // Sets timeout for 1 hour
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it had something to do with setTimeout, I just wasn't sure exactly how it would be coded.

Comment: @pause if that solved your problem, could you please accept this answer by clicking the tick on the left? This will mark your question as resolved ;) –

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
.then(m => m.delete(time in ms));
```

after the message.
Or, if you want to edit it before you delete it:

```
const msg = await message.channel.send("Edit message!")
msg.edit("It's edited now!")
msg.edit("You can do it multiple times!")
// You can use a setTimeout() here if you want a delay. Also, make sure that this is in an async function
msg.delete()
```